# Explain the Go string concatenation function

Tags: string, go, memory, stack

Here's the Go official implementation of the string concatenation operation

```
// concatstrings implements a Go string concatenation x+y+z+...
// The operands are passed in the slice a.
// If buf != nil, the compiler has determined that the result does not
// escape the calling function, so the string data can be stored in buf
// if small enough.
func concatstrings(buf *tmpBuf, a []string) string {
    idx := 0
    l := 0
    count := 0
    for i, x := range a {
        n := len(x)
        if n == 0 {
            continue
        }
        if l+n < l {
            throw("string concatenation too long")
        }
        l += n
        count++
        idx = i
    }
    if count == 0 {
        return ""
    }

    // If there is just one string and either it is not on the stack
    // or our result does not escape the calling frame (buf != nil),
    // then we can return that string directly.
    if count == 1 && (buf != nil || !stringDataOnStack(a[idx])) {
        return a[idx]
    }
    s, b := rawstringtmp(buf, l)
    for _, x := range a {
        copy(b, x)
        b = b[len(x):]
    }
    return s
}
```

What I'm interested in is this part:

```
// If there is just one string and either it is not on the stack
// or our result does not escape the calling frame (buf != nil),
// then we can return that string directly.
if count == 1 && (buf != nil || !stringDataOnStack(a[idx])) {
    return a[idx]
}
```

Could someone explain why if the string is not already on the goroutine stack, or if the string does not escape to heap, then we can return it immediately? Thanks.

I brainstormed and researched for an hour but could not come up with a reasonable explanation.

Comment: If its on the stack it will be gone once the function returns. If it escapes it must be treated accordingly. Only if not stack and not escaping you can reuse it.

Comment: @Volker but in this case we're returning it directly, so the fact that "if it's on the stack it will be gone once the function returns" is irrelevant? The string gets returned, so it should be carried up the call stack, not disappear.